# Erro on Firebase Provider

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-multidex

I am experiencing the following issue in my app:

didn't find class com.google.firebase.provider

I've read it in some places and I should enable Multidex, but it didn't work either. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

**Along with enabling multidex, you also need to do the below:**

FirebaseInitProvider is required during startup.

So you must manually specify FirebaseInitProvider as required in the primary DEX file.

**build.gradle file**

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**multidex-config.txt (in the same directory as the build.gradle file)**

```
com/google/firebase/provider/FirebaseInitProvider.class
```

Use the below link for more info:

[link for more info](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Refer this link as well for your error:
[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#keep)

Comment: try with this workaround!

Comment: yes u need to create

Comment: Hello, I tried but it did not work, try the following error: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.appssociety.mathapp, PID: 22473
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.appssociety.mathapp-6rkKpVqbO7GRhjvrFCEqlA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.appssociety.mathapp-6rkKpVqbO7GRhjvrFCEqlA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64

Comment: try to rebuild the project! or invalidate cache as well. You also need to enable multidex as well. For the solution to work

Comment: I activated Multidex and did what you said, but I get the same error. I also tried to enable proguard, but to no avail with app.

Comment: u getting the same error msg??

Comment: Yes, same erro!

Comment: refer the updated new link which i added for the doc. 
Also, have you added the multidex dependecy ?? and made changes to the manifest file as well?????

Comment: New erro: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.appssociety.mathapp, PID: 7185
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.appssociety.mathapp-fnhGrG98yVmRwKugrFBy5Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.appssociety.mathapp-fnhGrG98yVmRwKugrFBy5Q==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]

Comment: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "aq" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.appssociety.mathapp-lTawyyDo7WcPuI9fouvUZA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.appssociety.mathapp-lTawyyDo7WcPuI9fouvUZA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
 ... 14 more

Comment: hv u made changes to dependency and manifest???

Comment: Yes, I made all the changes

Comment: Proguard is active, is this a problem?

Comment: guess so try to disable it once nd check